# PHP' glob() to select images

Tags: php

In my case I have a folder with a lot of images. In my source I want to get all images of ONE product.

E.g the **product ID (PID)** is **12345**, in my folder I have images like:

```
123456789.jpg
123.jpg
1234.png
12345.png
12345-1.jpg
123456-1.bmp
12345-2.gif
```

The images I want to select is:

```
12345.png
12345-1.jpg
12345-2.gif
```

All other images or not from that product.

At the moment I select them like:

```
glob("path/to/the/images/" . $product_id . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE);
```

problem is.. this also brings me images like:

```
123456789.jpg
123456-1.bmp
```

Is it possible to say: bring me all images that matches the **PID** followed by a **DOT** **(.)** and all images that matches the **PID** followed by a **MINUS** **(-)** ?

I am [testing it here](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJwrSCzJ0C%2FJ18%2Bt1M%2FMTUxPLdY3NDI2MdXTAgB0rQgA&r=eJy9ku8KgjAUxV9F9t0t579mc%2B8yTefCzdFGZE%2BfsqAgCoLZ%2FXi555wfh0uP8hK1I7e2BoAZ7gbkJqRmJBUXnUUJTrO8KPcEnoygaLlm9LuEWsN1ZN08djXoJ%2B1iK29dFSUE4t06ZYFJSnJzPQC2%2BnvnVcVoc2bbhGSvKb%2BIPZLXvZEp7tohCF4OjQ7PFwYtTjYpLwxcsdA1yvyD7tEGhkL2nz71ub8DlTEMSQ%3D%3D&) and of course in my source since a while but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
glob("path/to/the/images/" . $product_id . "[.-]*", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: this nailed it :) thank you very much! I'll accept as soon as possile.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as an if statement, like the below

```
if(glob("path/to/the/images/*" . $product_id . ".*", GLOB_BRACE) 
    OR glob("path/to/the/images/" . $product_id . "-*", GLOB_BRACE)) { 
       //DO Stuff 
}
```

Comment: actually the part with `/*" . $product_id . ".*"` would give me wrong results! because the * in the front would make images like abd12345.xy match and that's no what I want :) also using If's is a thing that I tried to denie with the glob params. But thank you anyways.

Comment: No worries, Ahmed's response is much cleaner!

Comment: Indeed, I agree with you.